# Cannot collect environment data with Azure spatial anchors Unity android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I am using the following example to create the Azure spatial Anchors (ASA) demo app here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-android?tabs=azure-portal

Using the following SDK and Unity versions I cannot get the app to collect the environment data in order to save the data and anchor to my Azure Portal. I have successfully built an iOS version of the app, but the Android version fails to collect any environment data and gets stuck at 0%.

Unity: 2020.3.12f1
ARFoundation: 4.0.12
ARCore XR Plugin: 4.0.12
ARKit XR Plugin: 4.0.12
Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core: 2.10.2
Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Android: 2.10.2
Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for iOS: 2.10.2

Any ideas? I've tried updating ARFoundation and the XR plugins to 4.1.7 but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, you might be encountering the same problem mentioned in these two [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/306) [issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/244).

A bug that was impacting specific Android phones (e.g. Moto G50) [should be fixed with the release of ASA SDK 2.11.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/244#issuecomment-953262432)